# How to automatically identify citations of the same paper?

Tags: python, string-comparison, similarity, citations

Consider 3 ways to cite the same paper:

```
cite1 = "Yoshua Bengio, Réjean Ducharme, Pascal Vincent and Christian Jauvin, A Neural Probabilistic Language Model (2003), in: Journal of Machine Learning Research, 3(1137--1155)"

cite2 = "Yoshua Bengio, Réjean Ducharme, Pascal Vincent, Christian Jauvin. (2003) A Neural Probabilistic Language Model"

cite3 = "Bengio Y, Ducharme R, Vincent P, Jauvin C. (2003) A Neural Probabilistic Language Model"
```

A simple way of automatically identifying citations of the same paper is to compute the similarity of those citations with the `difflib` module in the Python Standard Library:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher as smatch
def similar(x, y): return smatch(None, x.strip(), y.strip()).ratio()

similar(cite1, cite2)    # 0.721
similar(cite1, cite3)    # 0.553
similar(cite2, cite3)    # 0.802
```

Unfortunately, the similarity metric ranges from 0.553 to 0.802 so it's not clear what threshold should be set. If the threshold is too low, then citations of different papers could be mistaken as the same paper. But if the threshold is too high, then we miss out some citations.

Are there better solutions?

Answer (score 1):

It is important to consider **What makes a citation unique?**

Based on your example, it appears that the combination of authors, the title of the article, and what year it was published constitutes a unique citation.

This means that you can parse the names, then compare how close they are (Because the third example lists the names differently). Parse the title, and it should match 100%. Parse the year, and it should also be a 100% match.

Answer (score 1):

Apart neural networks and NLP, which would be a rather ... complicated approach, i would approach this problem by preprocessing the data.

Few things you can do:

```
- Create Short names Yoshua Bengio => Bengio Y
- Normalize the names: Réjean Ducharme -> rejean ducharme
- Extract author part of the string, title part of the string, and the "leftovers". Calculate similarity for each of the parts and average the result.
- Extract the year of the publication and make it a three variable problem.
- Use additional metadata if available (paper field, citation index, etc.
```

The above approach works if your problem is limited to these three bibliography types.

If you have large variations amongst the bibliography (i.e. apply it on entire springer/ieee database) you should look into machine learning approaches.

While i cant suggest a correct model on top of my head, i remember [this](http://ants.iis.sinica.edu.tw/3BkMJ9lTeWXTSrrvNoKNFDxRm3zFwRR/55/Sentence%20Similarity%20Based%20on%20Semantic%20Nets%20and%20corpus%20statistics.pdf) paper being somewhere close to your problem.

Amongst other approaches, if you have a large dataset of bibliography, you can attempt semi supervised approaches like word2vec/node2vec or kmeans and see if the subsequent similarity score would be accurate enough for you.

**A word of advice.**

- in some cases you have very similar paper names coming along from the same research teams or short names being identical when long ones differ W. Xu can be either `Wang Xu` or `Wei Xu` are both transcribed to `Xu W.`.
- in other cases you have same authors having different names `Réjean Ducharme` and `Rejean Ducharme`
- Paper titles can have variations: `Conference of awesome discoveries` and `Awesome discoveries, conference of`